# To apply sharpness function over a certain region of image OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to apply the Tenengrad algorithm to a central rectangular region inside the image. Assuming that I have the coordinates of the vertices of the rectangular region or maybe one corner and the dimensions, how can I modify the following code to apply the sharpness measure over the selected region ?

```
double tenengrad(const cv::Mat& src, int ksize)
{
    cv::Mat Gx, Gy;
    cv::Sobel(src, Gx, CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize);
    cv::Sobel(src, Gy, CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize);

    cv::Mat FM = Gx.mul(Gx) + Gy.mul(Gy);

    double focusMeasure = cv::mean(FM).val[0];
    return focusMeasure;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cv::Mat imageRegion;
imageRegion = src(cv::Rect(x, y, width, height));
```

creates a matrix that points to the region of the original image specified by the rectangle (x, y, width, height). Modifying imageRegion will modify the original image `src`. So you can use `imageRegion` instead of `src`

```
 cv::Mat Gx, Gy;
 cv::Sobel(imageRegion, Gx, CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize);
 cv::Sobel(imageRegion, Gy, CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize);

 cv::Mat FM = Gx.mul(Gx) + Gy.mul(Gy);

 double focusMeasure = cv::mean(FM).val[0];
```